# How to hide trait implementation in Rust

Tags: rust, error-handling

I have a project with its own error type, which is exposed outside of crate. Lets call it `MyErrorType`. The project itself *internally* depends on another crate with its own error type. Lets call it `ForeignErrorType`.

In order to simplify code and make it more readable I've created following implementation of [From](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/convert/trait.From.html) trait:

```
impl From<ForeignErrorType> for MyErrorType {
   ...
}
```

This allows to use question mark operator, `?`, when dealing with foreign error types without a necessity to convert them in place.

The issue is that the mentioned trait implementation is exposed outside of my crate. I don't want the users of my crate to accidentally rely on the conversion possibility from `ForeignErrorType` to `MyErrorType`.

*What I've tried so far:* Have put the mentioned trait implementation into module with `pub(crate)` visibility. This surprisingly hides all `struct`s defined in such module, but leaves trait implementation exposed.

- Is there way to keep my `From` implementation private and not to expose it outside of crate?
- Probably I'm trying to achieve error handling benefits in a non‑idiomatic way. If this is true, what's the proper way to be able to use `?` operator on foreign error types without exposing them?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want consumers of your API to be able to use the `From` implementation? A simpler way could be to define a `pub(crate)` function called `transform_err` or something, and whenever returning a `Result<_, ForeignError>`, you call `map_err` manually. Sure it's more keystrokes but gets the job done?

Comment: *why don't you want consumers of your API to be able to use the From implementation?* Let's say at some time in future I would like to use another crate internally, If there are no parts of the previously used crate are exposed outside, I'll simply need to adjust internal code. Otherwise, it's a breaking change to API. *A simpler way could be...* I consider it as a fallback option. But having a simple ```?``` instead of an additional function is slightly more readable

Comment: I guess the simplest way would be to create a wrapper struct that is the one exposed, and which actually doesnt implement anything itself except Error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there way to keep my `From` implementation private and not to expose it outside of crate?

No. Trait implementations have no scope.

What you can do instead in this case is write a function with the same contents as your `From` implementation would have had, and apply it with `Result::map_err` before `?`.

```rust
pub(crate) fn foreign_err(e: ForeignErrorType) -> MyErrorType {
    todo!()
}

...

let foo = their_function().map_err(foreign_err)?;
```

This has to be done at every `?` usage, but there is no way to have an implicit conversion that is scoped to a crate or module, so that's the best you can have.